# JEditorPane is blocking the divider of a JSplitPane

Tags: java, swing, awt, jeditorpane, jsplitpane

In my application I'm using a JSplitPane to devide the GUI into two sides. Every side will contain some components, one of them being a JEditorPane. The components are placed horizontally next to each other. All components should have a fixed size exept for the JEditorPanel. This should take all the available horizontal space. So, if the divider of the splitPane is moved the JEditorPane should change its width. My current implementation works fine if the divider is moved in a direction where the with of the JSplitPane increases. However, it is not possible to move the divider in the other direction. Below is a minimalistic example of my problem. In the example I'm using a GridbagLayout. However, this problem remains also for other layout manager. Also interesting is that this problem seems to be unique for the JEditorPane. The implementation works fine when the JEditorPane is replaced, for example by a JButton.
Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setSize(500, 500);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panelRight = new JPanel();
        JPanel panelLeft = new JPanel();

        panelRight.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        JButton b = new JButton("button");
        c.gridx = 1;
        c.gridy = 0;
        panelRight.add(b, c);

        JEditorPane ep = new JEditorPane();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 1;
        panelRight.add(ep, c);

        JSplitPane sp = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, panelLeft, panelRight);
        sp.setResizeWeight(0.5);

        f.add(sp);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why this is happending and/or how to fix it?

Comment: maybe setting/changing the minimum size (width) of the `JEditorPane` (but will disable its calculation by the components UI) - This behavior is documented in the `JSplitPane` class: "*When the user is resizing the Components the minimum size of the Components is used to determine the maximum/minimum position the Components can be set to. ... To alter the minimum size of a JComponent, see JComponent.setMinimumSize(java.awt.Dimension).*"

Comment: on the other side, if no minimum size is set, the available size from the split pane is used - consequently the divider will never be allowed to *shrink* the editor pane if no minimum size is set

Comment: thanks, I missed that. You can post this comment as an answer, then I can accept it